# Capture NOTICE from PostgreSQL in Perl DBI

Tags: postgresql, perl, error-handling

I'm using full text search with user generated input on a PostgreSQL table, "the a" in this example.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("...", { RaiseError => 0, AutoCommit => 1 });
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name from mytable WHERE tsv @@ plainto_tsquery('the a')");
my $rv = $sth->execute();
```

If the user input only contains stop words, I get a NOTICE on STDERR and the query returns no results, but produces no error.

I would like to capture that NOTICE in Perl to possibly alert the user to rephrase the search, but I can't seem to access it.

Setting RaiseError to 1 doesn't change anything and $dbh->pg_notifies returns undef.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume that the mention of "NOTICE" means that something does a `RAISE`. How that behaves is [configurable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config.html) but delving into that would require far more detail.

At perl level, there are various ways to get to the `STDERR` stream and capture what's sent to it.

If these are [warn](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn)-ings then setting a hook for `$SIG{__WARN__}` runs that subroutine whenever a warning is to be printed

```
{
    local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { say "Got warning: $_[0]"; };

    warn "a warning";
}
```

So you can capture it this way, do what you wish with it, and then perhaps reemit.  The `$_[0]` in the example has the string `a warning`, and after the anonymous sub runs the control is back at the next line after a warning is issued (the `warn` statement in this snippet).  See [%SIG](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#%25SIG).

I put this in a block only to be able to [local](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local)-ize the change to `SIG{__WARN__}`, what is practically compulsory (if this global isn't `local`-ized its change affects all code). So if this code is in a suitable lexical scope anyway then that block isn't needed.

But this won't catch things printed directly to `STDERR`. For that the most practical way is to use libraries, and a simple and convenient one for this purpose is [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny)

```
use Capture::Tiny qw(capture);

my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = capture { 
    say "to STDOUT"; 
    say STDERR "to STDERR"; 
    warn "a warn-ing"; 
    # ...
};
```

Now `$stdout` has text `to STDOUT` while `$stderr` has `to STDERR` followed by `a warn-ing`.  So your database code would go in such a block and the NOTICE should wind up in that `$stderr` variable.  There is also a `capture_stderr` function if you prefer to capture only that this way.

Comment: Capturing via `$SIG{__WARN__}` works. Thanks!

Comment: @GeneVincent Great -- thanks for letting me know.  (Then I'd hope that the module can capture it as well.  While use of the `$SIG{__WARN__}` requires no changes to the other code, except perhaps scope-related tweaks.)

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't seem to work as it should, and it is recognized as an [unsolved bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=88332).